# Eclipse Javascript syntax highlighting broken after update?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, updates, eclipse-2020-06

After the recent Eclipse update (Version 4.17.0, Build 20200910-1200) the syntax highlighting for Javascript files is not working any longer. Furthermore the *.js file association and the Textmate section are missing in the preferences.

Does anybody experience similar problems?

Comment: I googled it for you ... https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564496 ... seems to be 4.16 where this stopped working (something about standalone js editor or something) anyway, read that, follow some links, you may find an answer

Comment: That wasn't the problem but thx anyway :-) ... Figured it out myself in the meantime. With the recent update to 4.17 the Wild Web Developer (responsible for JS support since 4.15) was just missing and I had to reinstall it manually.

Comment: What were you running before the update?

Comment: Wild Web Developer that was originally delivered with 2020-06/09. Why it did not work after the JDK15 update I can not say.